# Which logo does this word represent?

Tags: wordplay, cipher, visual, word-property, anagram

## Puzzle 1

Which logo does the word **dsPlinS** represent?

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

3.

[image]

4.

[image]

5.

[image]

I haven't posted in a while, but I'm back on track, baby! And to celebrate my coming back, whoever solves this would earn a $50$ rep bounty and a tick! It shouldn't be too hard. I have chosen logos with circles because of the following hint:

**Hint:**

> *What goes around, comes around.*

Enjoy! :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @alex oland got the right answer, and with the hint given,

> Rotate the image and we can see the letters dsPlinS
>
>  [image]

Comment: Correcto! Congratulations :D $$(+1) \ \ \color{green}{\checkmark}$$

Answer (score 3):

First guess:

> "dsPlinS" S,s,n,i four letters match the word: "Sunkist" which is the most in all of the logos. Therefore: two

Second guess:

> With the phrase you have given: first logo: one matches - second logo: four matches - third logo: two matches - fourth logo: 1 matches - fifth logo: 2 matches. Let's assume that the matches tell us what number we have to look at. For example: third logo has two matches so you look at two. Second logo has four matches so you look at four. Fourth logo has one matches so you look at one. First logo has one matches. Therefore it can also be the first logo. In better wording: First logo is the only logo that has the same amount of matches as it's number

Comment: You have the correct answer, but not the correct reasoning. But don’t worry — I am sure you’ll find out. No background knowledge is required. All you need is the logo... and a good eye, puelo xale ;)

Answer (score 3):

My guess will have to be:

> Coca-Cola

My reasons are as follows:

> At first, I noticed the word **dsPlinS** was similar to the word DSpline, a RealFlow editing effect most commonly used in Coca-Cola advertisements, however, most soda commercials have this effect in their advertising. So why did I answer Coca-Cola? The reason is due to the hint given: What comes around, goes around! You see, I did some research and discovered that there was a 2006 commercial provided by Coca-Cola with the same song title, thus concluding that this must of been the correct solution. I hope my reasons were somewhat efficient!

Comment: Wow.... that is not the answer, but what a freaky coincidence... I might have to give you the $50$ rep bounty, but not the tick, because it isn’t the answer. But mate... that is creepy. $(+1)$ :P